Copy a mobile number from Google, click the call icon on the Google screen, and redirect to the `MainActivity` screen in an Android Java application
I am implementing a feature similar to Google’s functionality, where the user can copy a mobile number and click the call icon on the same screen. This action should redirect the user to the MainActivity screen in an Android Java application. I am attaching a reference screen for better understanding.
I attempted to implement the functionality of copying a mobile number from Google and clicking the call icon to redirect the user to the MainActivity in an Android Java application. I expected the app to launch MainActivity automatically upon clicking the call icon, passing the copied number as an intent extra.
